# localStorage is not visible in iFrame

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, local-storage, third-party-cookies

We have a sporadic issue when we setup some data to the localStorage in a separate tab, then when we load the same domain in the same browser in iFrame under another domain, we don't see those data. The issue happens only to some specific user and locally we can not reproduce it.

Most of users who has this issue are using Windows OS. The workflow we use is the next.

1. Open a new tab with a project domain like **internal.com**
2. Login the user and store the access token to the **localStorage**
3. Open client's project domain like **external.com**
4. Make sure that 3rd-party cookies are enabled
5. Add an **iFrame** under **external.com** with the **internal.com** address
6. Verify that the content of **internal.com** is loaded in **iFrame** as expected

*What is the expected result?*

In the **localStorage** of the **iFrame** with the **internal.com** address under the **external.com** tab, we should see the data we set in the browser tab with the **internal.com** address

*What happens instead?*

The **localStorage** of the **iFrame** with the **internal.com** address under the **external.com** tab is empty.

We started getting such issue since the beginnign of August, approximately.
Anybody has faced the same or know the reason?

We've checked all the possible browser settings, insluding 3rd-party cookies and CORS policies.

---

Here are some official resources to follow-up the issue:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1482192#c9
- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/24hK6DKJnqY/m/ChL2WWx5CgAJ
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1476059

Answer (score 5):

I was fighting to it all day long.

https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

That was the reason. New chrome experimental feature. Just disable it.

chrome://flags/#third-party-storage-partitioning.

Also check your browser third party cookie permissions. It also should be allowed.

Comment: Ok, but how to make it work for every client? I cannot ask all of them to disable this feature. We have an application (called `A`) which stores data in local storage and that data should be retrievable when `A` is embedded into other pages as `iframe`. But with this chrome feature now the webpage `A` cannot see it's own saved data in local storage when embedded into other pages.

Comment: @ktamas as far as I know there's currently no way that you can programmatically solve this. There's a discussion to create an API to using localStorage with default partition, you can follow the issue here https://github.com/privacycg/storage-access/issues/102