# msal-broswer doesn't save auth token inside local session with new chrome version

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, azure-ad-msal, teams-toolkit, msal-react

i've a teams react app, but from last chrome update, with msal i'm not able to save token authentication inside local session. That's my configuration.

- msal-broswer: 2.38.1
- chrome version: 117
- msal-configuration:
  `

```
{
    auth: {
        clientId: config.clientId,
        authority: Config.authority,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    }
}
```

I tried to downgrade chrome version and everthings works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by taking inspiration from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096988/localstorage-is-not-visible-in-iframe) ,
I disable "Experimental third-party storage partitioning" from the experimental flag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your MSAL library is up to date. Outdated versions might not be fully compatible with the latest browser changes.

Comment: Nothing, updated all library up to last version, still not working. During all api invoke, popup for reauth always appear and no data stored inside local storage